# How can you make an infinity efficiency pickaxe using commands?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

This video right here by Phoenix SC:

and go to 3:02. In that video, he made a pickaxe that has infinity efficiency.

Do you have an idea on how to make this pickaxe using commands in 1.16?

Comment: The highest obtainable level of enchantments in vanilla minecraft is 32 767 and can only be obtained using the give command.

Answer (score 3):

There is no means by which you can attain an infinity-level enchantment in unmodded Minecraft.